# SVG gradient not applied on MS Edge in Aurelia application

Tags: svg, aurelia, microsoft-edge

I am building an [AureliaJS](http://aurelia.io) based application which contains a SVG based component. My problem is that in MS Edge, the gradients of this SVG are not rendered (see image below: the "gauge" is supposed to be transparent and the two circles green). It is correctly displayed in all the other browsers I tested (FireFox, IE11, Chrome).

The gradients are defined inside the SVG in a `defs` section. They are then used by their ids.

I tried:

- To open the SVG part of the component as an SVG file in Edge. Strangely it renders correctly. So I guess the SVG is correct.
- To remove the Aurelia markup: the problem is still here.
- To change the value of fill (currently `fill: url(#gauge-fill-2)`) into `fill: url('#gauge-fill-2')` or `fill: url('/#gauge-fill-2')` without success.

[image]

I also get the message below in the console, which disappears if I remove this SVG (I translated it from French as I have a French edition of Windows 10)

`XML5633: The name of the ending tag doesn't match the name of the starting tag.
Line. 60, column 7`

However, when I read the code, I couldn't find any problem about closing tags. To be sure of this, I remove most of the code and left only one element with a gradient on it. This message was still there.

The full code of the component is available here: https://bitbucket.org/arenaoftitans/arena-of-titans/src/9f5f70ff3fc71832bcac90ce0dcc5204a471b095/app/game/play/widgets/gauge/gauge.html?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

Any idea of what the problem might be and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by the creators update. I just need for it to be widely deployed.